# serial type produce only even or odd numbers in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, nextval

I want set some constraint to the serial type,it only produce even or odd numbers.

Answer (score 6):

`SERIAL` is a [syntax sugar](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) around creating and using sequences.

So you could do it all manually and [create](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) a special type of sequence that suits your needs:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 2;

CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq');

ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

Or if you already have a table and a `SERIAL` column you could [change](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html) the underlying sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq INCREMENT BY 2;
```

The name of the underlying sequence could be retrieved by "describing" the table using [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

```
\d tablename
```

Comment: I already have a sequence, and curval is 3,but I want to product even numbers 4,6,8,10...

Answer (score 4):

Simply, set your serial to increment by 2, and to start on either 1 or 2 for producing either odd or even number:

Odd

```
CREATE SEQUENCE odd_seq INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 1;
```

Even

```
CREATE SEQUENCE even_seq INCREMENT BY 2 START WITH 2;
```

Comment: could I change the default create sequence increment by 2?